# Responsive image sizing constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I got a constraintlayout with five images in a row inside of it. My problem is that I want to have the size of these images responsive, so that now matter how small the width of a screen is, all of the images are shown.

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:text="This ist the title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/smartphone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:textAppearance="@style/introductionTitle"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/smartphone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_smartphone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_next_dark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/smartphone"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_store"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/next"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/next2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_next_dark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/shop"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/coffee"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_coffee"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/next2"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

At the moment, this is what it looks like on differen screens:
preferably the images would be centered horizontally together. To achieve this I put them in a `LinearLayout` and this did work but I couldn't fix the responsiveness problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set:

```
android:layout_width = "0dp";
android:layout_weight = 1;
```

In all 5 Views, so they will cover your parent_layout_width with relative weights, in this case they all be equal width.

Comment: This is almost what I need. The bad sideeffect of this one is, that the distance between the images is bigger now when the screen is bigger.

Comment: post a screenshot, don't understand exactly what a problem?

Comment: there should be no space between these images. So when the screen is very big they should still stay together in the middle of the screen. But now thay equaly take the space of the width from the screen, so it will look stretched out on biggetr screens.

Comment: your 'linear_layout:width'? may be try 'wrap_content'